# How do i get the submit button to check the validation of a login before redirecting in PHP?

Tags: php, html, validation, authentication, submit

I would like my login to check if the details are correct i put into the username and password boxes before taking me to the next page, and preferably i would like an error to appear. Whats the best way to do this? (I am not too bothered about security at the moment and im planning to tackle that at a later stage) My code is posted below, thank you - Novice PHP developer.

Also any tips that you can give on the lay out of my code or the way i have wrote this are more than welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body style = "background-color:purple">

<?php

if (isset($_GET['userName'])) {

    echo "<p>user name is " . $_GET['userName'] . "</p>";

    // try and log in
    $userName =  $_GET['userName'];
    $password =  $_GET['password'];

    if (($userName == "Admin") && ($password == "podpoint")) {
        echo "correct details" ;
    } 
    else 
        echo "Incorrect username or password";


} else {

    // show the login form
    ?>

<center></center><form name="input" action="reserved_page.php" method="get">
    <center><p style="color:white">Username: <input type="text" name="userName"></p>
    <center><p style="color:white">Password: <input type="text" name="password"></p>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
}
?>
</body>
```

Comment: html code tip: the `<center>` tags are deprecated; you should put styling information in CSS; the same goes for the `style=...` attributes. General tip: do a google search for form creation and validation: there are LOADS of tutorials out there that will teach you how to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing you'd generally use Javascript.

W3Schools has a nice tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

For example, validating that username has a value:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["input"]["userName"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Username must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

You would then usually have the name/password checks (often against a database) on another php file, which then handles the input and lets you know whether the login was successful or not, as opposed to doing it all in one file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery then try following:(you can check by on click of run snippet)

```css
input.error{
   border: 1px dotted red;
}
label.error{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<center></center>

<form name="input" id="frm" action="reserved_page.php" method="get">
    <center><p style="color:white">Username: <input type="text" name="userName" class="required"></p>
    <center><p style="color:white">Password: <input type="text" name="password" class="required"></p>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        /* form validate */
        $("#frm").validate();
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: At least clean up the html... it's horrible!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the action target of your form to file name itself to validate the data.
if you save the codes to index.php then you should put action="index.php". 
in that case you can check if the validation is correct and redirect to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't really get your point. I'm at work right now so I can't offer specific code examples but this is probably the easiest way to do it:

1. Set the action to the form file itself
2. Above the form markup you add the Php code similar to your work so far
3. Check if the server request method equals "post" like this:

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){ ... }
4. If this statement is true you're gonna check the entered values and if they are correct you redirect to another page or just show a success message and start the session http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson12.php

4.1 If you redirect to another page it's important to check if the user is actually logged in. the easiest way to do that is to set a session if the form validation was successfull. So on the second page you're gonna check if the login session has been set for the user by entering the correct values. if true, you're gonna show the content and if the cookie has not been set you're gonna redirect back to the form

5. If the statement is false you're just gonna show the form within the else{...} part

Hope you know what I mean